# SAS prxparse to extract a string

Tags: regex, sas

I wish to extract the two words "blood" and "loss" within the closest proximity to a substring. I have the codes below, but the ID 4 didn't work. I wish to get the substring "blood loss", not "bloods but blood loss".

```
data test;
  infile datalines truncover;
  input id $2. string $80.;
  datalines;
1 there is one blood something loss
2 no something else here
3 three blood loss again blood loss can not believe loss of blood
4 two bloods but blood loss
;
run;


data test1;
  set test;
  rx=prxparse("/blood.*?loss|loss.*?blood/i");
  start=1;
  stop =length(trim(string));
  do until (p=0);
    call prxnext(rx,start,stop,trim(string),p,l);
    if p>0  then do; 
       sub=substr(string,p,l);
       output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Please don't include name or email in the question (and email shouldn't be anywhere here visible, it's easily scraped by spammers).

Comment: You want to match "blood" but not "bloods", or is "bloods" okay to match if it does turn out to be the closest match?

Comment: Please rephrase "close proximity", update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Very small change is needed, if blood**s** need to be ignored. Add a space between the blood and **.** in the first part of regex and it will try and match the word blood. Below is the replacement prxparse statement.

```
rx=prxparse("/blood .*?loss|loss.*?blood/i");
```

---

As per the updated comment, for matching string "blood loss" when string is like "blood something blood loss" then negative lookahead can help.

```
prxparse("/blood (.(?!blood))*?loss/i")
```

Comment: Thanks, Sushil, for your kind answer. Actually, sometimes it could be a string like "blood something blood loss". And I wish to get extract the "blood loss", not "blood something blood loss". Any ideas? Thanks a million

Comment: I have provided a new regex for matching the case you've mentioned

Comment: Sushil, you are a genius. It worked like a charm. Hats off to you.